# Running < 20 classic asp sites on 2008 IIS7. Memory use brings the server to its knees

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, memory, cache, asp

I am hosting < 20 asp classic websites on a Windows 2008 Server. All of the websites run on my custom CMS.  I am migrating them from a 2003 server.

Memory was also an issue when these sites were hosted on 2003, but not nearly as severe.

On the 2008 server, When a visitor visits any page on any on any of my sites, the server consumes approximately 30 megs of Private Bytes and 40 megs of Working Set RAM.  This is for each page.  1 visitor, 1 page.

If recycling is not performed frequently, the site will virtually lock up.

I believe the issue is that my CMS is too heavy with #includes (I have tested this theory successfully), and I believe IIS is caching the entire thing.

Can I limit the amount of memory that w3wp.exe consumes when caching these pages or even turn caching off entirely?  I have tried settings in IIS and with the exception of setting Recycling Memory Limits, I cannot change the amount of memory w3wp.exe uses for each app pool.

Frequent Recycling is not desirable.

I would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Fix the memory leak in the code?

Comment: Also: details? Amount of RAM? Number of app pools, app pool configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean over and above the baseline memory use of the W3WP? 30/40MB is a kinda-normal sounding number for a "warm up the pool" request.

Just because 1 user, 1 page uses 30/40MB doesn't mean that 20 users of that page would use significantly more. ASP has some startup overhead that gets amortized over all the users of that page/site.

Are the apps all different sites? Have you tried consolidating them into fewer App Pools (as presumably might have been the case in IIS 6?)

You can run app pools as 32-bit to limit their memory use, but you can't specify an actual limit they're constrained to, only the point at which they recycle at (this depends on your app framework).

You can look into using WSRM to constrain memory, but fixing the code or finding the option causing the behavior change is the better option.